# How do I deregister device in MFP

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am sending push notification via an external script and capturing the response that is return from MobileFirst. The response is always 200 and a messageId is in the response JSON object

How can I simulate a error condition?

I used the MFP API to remove the subscription, removing the device from the device tab in the MFP console. However, I can still send and receive push notification for that deviceID .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsubscribing from the tag subscription (which you have subscribed in the code) does not clear all subscriptions. A default Push.ALL tag subscription stays in the DB. This is why you are able to still send notifications.

You can remove the device registration either using the SDK ( as mentioned by Gaurab) or use the REST API call to do this.

Details here: [Push Device Registration Delete](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_registration_delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using IBM MobileFirst v8.0.

You need to implement these API in client side to unregister the device or unsubscribe from tags.

> Unregister the device from push notification service instance.

```
MFPPush.unregisterDevice(
    function(successResponse) {
        alert("Unregistered successfully");
    },
    function() {
        alert("Failed to unregister");
    }
);
```

> Unsubscribe from tags.

```
var tags = ['sample-tag1','sample-tag2'];

MFPPush.unsubscribe(
    tags,
    function(tags) {
        alert("Unsubscribed successfully");
    },
    function() {
        alert("Failed to unsubscribe");
    }
);
```